# Compiling code that uses Intel MKL modules with gfortran

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran, intel-mkl

I want to use `gfortran` to compile some code that uses `mlk_vsl.f90` from the Intel MKL library on a Mac.

I'm doing the following:
`gfortran -o filename filename.f90 -I/${MKLROOT}/include`

and I get this error:

```
"Can't open module file 'mkl_vsl_type.mod" for reading at (1): No such file or directory"
```

I know that I have to create the `.mod` file, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Do you have the MKL sources, containing the interfaces, from which to create the `.mod` files?

Comment: What does mkl_vsl.f90 contain? Does it contain the `mkl_vsl_type` module? Note that the exact linking instructions for MKL are on the Intel website. You can select several options and the site will give you the right command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track for compiling (if add `-c`). A few suggestions:

1. Try adding `-fno-range-check`, which is required to get gfortran to compile the mkl_vsl modules correctly (.mod files created automatically when you compile your main program)
2. Not knowing what is set for MKLROOT, you may have an extra backslash; try

   `-I${MKLROOT}/include`

However, for linking you probably need additional libraries. The easiest way to see how to link is to look at one of the examples in your MKLROOT dir `mkl/examples/vslf/source` which has source files that use mkl_vsl. In `mkl/examples/vslf` there is a makefile you can run to generate executables and print the link lines. Use `make help` for more info. For example, to compile vslssort.f with gfortran and static linking: `make libintel64 compiler=gnu function=vslssort`. Just note two caveats: The link line uses `libmkl_intel_thread.a` instead of `libmkl_gnu_thread.a`, and it uses the -J flag to put the created .mod files in a different directory which MUST be created before linking.